# Use of Pipelines to encrypt a file

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I have just startet working with crypto++ and i have a question about the piplenes and how to use them to encrypt a file.

I want to use AES to encrypt a file.

1.)Would it be enough to just do:

```
EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived.data(), 16, ivb, ivb.size());
FileSource f("source", new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,new FileSink("deststination")));
```

2.) If i have a huge input file, will this approach automaticly encrypt the files in blocks?

3.) Would this automaticly create the output file if it is not there?

**EDIT:**

Ok, i got it to wok with my approch.

The 2.) Question remains and i have a new one:

Can I tell it to skip the first 24 bytes of the file?

Comment: Have a look at [`BufferedTransformation`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_buffered_transformation.html#details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
> encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived.data(), 16, ivb, ivb.size());
> FileSource f("source", new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,new FileSink("deststination")));
> ```

Close. The `AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter` will be coerced to the `bool pumpAll` parameter of `FileSink`. So you need:

```
FileSource f("source", true, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,new FileSink("deststination")));
```

Also see [FileSource](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource) on the Crypto++ wiki. And the [FileSource Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html) from the manual might be of interest, too.

---

> If i have a huge input file, will this approach automatically encrypt the files in blocks?

Yes. Internally, Crypto++ will "block" or "chunk" the processing in 4096-bytes, IIRC. A recent discussion about it occurred on the mailing list at [ios locking up during encryption](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/WezFWb9XQ84/rnHGDTO9CwAJ).

A program that [allows you to do the blocking](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/WezFWb9XQ84/NoFUitCrDQAJ) is provided in the post. You can use it to throttle the processing, a place to update a progress bar or yield the processor, if needed. Its reproduced below.

---

> Would this automatically create the output file if it is not there?

Yes. The `FileSource` is just a `std::ifstream` wrapper, while a `FileSink` is just a `std::ofstream` wrapper.

Again, here are the wiki pages:

- [FileSource](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource)
- [FileSink](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSink)

---

> Can I tell it to skip the first 24 bytes of the file?

Yes. In this case, use `bool pumpAll` and set it to `false`. Then do something like:

```
FileSource fs("source", false, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(...));
fs.Skip(24);

size_t remaining = <size of file>;
size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
while(remaining && !fs.SourceExhausted())
{    
    const unsigned int req = STDMIN(remaining, BLOCK_SIZE);
    fs.Pump(req);
    fs.Flush(false);

    remaining -= req;
}
```

Or, you can:

```
FileSource fs("source", false, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(...));
fs.Skip(24);
fs.PumpAll();
```

Also see [FileSource Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html) in the manual. `Skip` is part of `BufferedTransformation`; and `PumpAll` is part of `Source`.

---

There are also wiki pages covering EAX mode and the authenticated {en|de}cryption filters. See:

- [EAX Mode](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Eax_mode)
- [AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter)
- [AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter)

There's even a page on using a Java-like Init/Update/Final at:

- [Init-Update-Final](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Init-Update-Final)

---

The program below uses ***`CFB_Mode<AES>`***, but its easy enough to swap in another cipher and mode. It also demonstrates how to place objects on the stack and use them in a pipeline rather than creating them on the heap with ***`new`***.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  static const unsigned int BIG_SIZE = 2U * 1024U * 1024U;    
  static const unsigned int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096U;

  try
    {
      SecByteBlock key(32);
      OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, key.data(), key.size());

      // cout << "Key: ";
      // ArraySource as(key.data(), key.size(), true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(cout)));
      // cout << endl;

      CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
      enc.SetKeyWithIV(key.data(), key.size(), key.data());

      MeterFilter meter;
      StreamTransformationFilter stf(enc);

      FileSource source("/dev/zero", false);
      FileSink sink("zero.enc");

      source.Attach(new Redirector(stf));
      stf.Attach(new Redirector(meter));
      meter.Attach(new Redirector(sink));    

      unsigned int remaining = BIG_SIZE;
      while(remaining && !source.SourceExhausted())
      {
        if(remaining % (1024) == 0)
        {
          cout << "Processed: " << meter.GetTotalBytes() << endl;    
        }

        const unsigned int req = STDMIN(remaining, BLOCK_SIZE);
        source.Pump(req);
        source.Flush(false);

        remaining -= req;
    }
  }
  catch(const Exception& ex)
  {
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this anwer, helped me alot.